# Force rectangle out of div[overflow: hidden] to the right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gif: https://gyazo.com/222623a5c9c54588ed02c3423d5f2bcc

As you can see, looking at the gif, the rectangle is floated down left out of view. This is not what I want. I want it to be pushed out to the right, slowly going out of view. How should this be done?

Here is a little js fiddle prototype, so you dont have to start from scratch: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastian3495/y3nume0p/42/ (*You might want to run the code locally or somewhere else, seems like there is a problem with jquery*)

What am I doing wrong?

---

css

```
div#main-content {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: hi, your fiddle's example is not working

Comment: @MaksymKoldun It works when I run it on my localhost, I think js fiddle has a problem loading jquery or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

(p.s - Your jsfiddle is broken so I can't check it)

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks a lot! Here is the result: https://gyazo.com/49aa6b202b60e12118bf885ac1b68015